# Custom User Login validation

Tags: users

I am developing a Mobile App for my drupal website, where user need to login with existing user account in drupal. How to validate password? I have tried MD5, and also concatinated it with $S$. Any suggestions..

Answer (score 3):

use [`user_hash_password()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/user_hash_password/7) to validate the password for existing users.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this.. Is it possible without using drupal functions.